# How can I use LocalSettings (UWP) in my ViewModel class?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, uwp, application-data

So I want to use LocalSettings (for UWP) inside my ViewModel class (so that I can persist data between views) but I keep getting this error in this screenshot: [image]

However, I try to add a reference to the assembly but nothing happens.

My ViewModel inherits from ViewModelBase (Common logic among all view models)

```
MyViewModel : ViewModelBase
```

Where `ViewModelBase : INotifyPropertyChanged, ILoadableViewModel, IVisibilityAwareViewModel`

What can I do to persist data between viewmodels in this scenario? I have a property in one of my viewmodels that I want to use in another viewmodel and that's where the issue lies.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use LocalSettings in PortableClassLibrary (PLC) .

When i need save data i use this plugin https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/SettingsPlugin . It's a great plugin . You should try it.

Comment: Can I use this for my PLC or .Net standard class?

Comment: yes, you can use this for PLC. A Plugin is like "External library". You only have add nuget package and use it.  Here is a sample https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/SettingsPlugin/tree/master/samples